# Is there a way for a house to adjust its temperature without any active heating and cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am aware of various forms of insulators that have different advantages in terms of how they regulate the temperature of a house. I am wondering whether or not a house can maintain a cool temperature during the summer without active cooling and a warm temperature during the winter without active heating and if this can be achieved with insulation and the laws of thermodynamics. Thanks!

Comment: Building a house from a material with higher heat capacity and lower heat conductivity gives a kind of "heat inertia" - the heat absorbed during warm periods stays longer during cold ones, and vice versa. Note that you're interested in the net effect of these factors. The best example is stone vs wood. Importantly, you're interested not in capacities per unit mass but the total ones (naïvely, for stone both are worse but it's way denser).

Comment: Yes, it is possible to design a house that is heated all year round by solar, without any other form of heat input - no fire, no gas heaters just underfloor heating driven from the solar heated hot water tank.

Comment: @SolarMike I understand that this is an option but I am trying to avoid any form of active heating like electrical or solar. I am asking about different forms of insulation or other materials that are capable of possibly moving around the heat energy?

Comment: @Razor anything that can move heat energy has to be "active" from what you are saying, so that means it is excluded...  I know of several houses that produce more energy over the year than they consume - **very** sustainable, just need an architect or heating engineer that understands the principles.

Comment: see https://zeroenergyhouse.co.nz/passive-heating-and-cooling  and https://blog.passivehouse-international.org/summer-comfort-passive-house/ . Search for "passive heating and cooling"